# Eclipse on Ubuntu taking up a lot of space

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, user-interface

I am running Eclipse under Ubuntu and the chrome takes up a lot of space.  I have reduced my system font to be smaller but the tabs and toolbars stay the same size resulting is a lot of wasted space.  Is there any way to change this?  I'd really like to have more room for the actual code editor.

[image: Whole Window]
[image: Close up of tabs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily expend the code editor to use the whole Eclipse UI by using the little expand button that is located on the top right corner of each of the views. When in need to go back to the standard view, the same button will resume the usual layout.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of hoping to find a way to make the UI smaller because I really like being able to see all of that stuff, I just want it to feel not so crowded.  But I'm accepting this because I think it's the best I'm going to get.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also find that the Eclipse UI consumes too many pixels on the screen.

You can change the preferences in : Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance.
I used the:

- "Eclipse 2.1 Style Presentation"
- "Default" theme
- "Show traditional style tabs" checked

This makes tabs height a little bit lower.